# C# WebBrowser child requests from the page don't have same headers

Tags: c#, http-headers, authorization, webbrowser-control

I have a C# Web browser control.  I pass in the Authrozation header into the browser in the .Navigate method.  The page then authorizes and loads fine.

The issue I have is that if the page has , those images then make new get requests, except those requests no longer have the Authorization header.

I thought that the child requests from the parent page carry the same headers from the response.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the case. It looks like headers do not persist across requests. Cookies are the way to go for this problem.